# How to compare two string arrays?

Tags: c#

```
string[] array1 = new string[]{"312" , "B"};

string[] array2 = new string[]{"AT" , "210" , "312"};

//If have a same elements (bool HaveSame) must be true because "312" have in both arrays
```

Selman22 thank you. and others i mean only C# but winforms i cant delate. that's why sorry for winforms. Beause i am a new user.

Comment: what has this to do with winforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this:

```
// 1
array1.Intersect(array2).Any();

// 2
array1.Except(array2).Count() == array1.Distinct().Count();

// 3.1
array1.Any(array2.Contains);

// 3.2
array1.All(x => !array2.Contains(x));
```

Comment: disregarding the low quality of the question, your answer will give different results for the given arrays ... it might just confuse the poor soul further ...